# How to polyfill performance.now in Rust WebAssembly

Tags: rust, webassembly, polyfills, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to use the [jwt_simple](https://docs.rs/jwt-simple/latest/jwt_simple/) library in a cloudflare workers webassembly runtime. Following the basic example in the linked documentation, everything works fine up until `key.authenticate(claims)?` is executed, at which point the following stack trace is generated in my terminal running wrangler:

```
ReferenceError: performance is not defined
    at __wbg_now_63f780680ee9cc56 (./index_bg.mjs:331:15)
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[264]:0x252a9
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[409]:0x2925d
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[167]:0x1fb99
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[410]:0x292b9
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[284]:0x25ea0
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[132]:0x1cbd9
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[38]:0x9bbc
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[143]:0x1dc3b
    at wasm://wasm/001926f2:wasm-function[106]:0x19ccb at line 330, col 13
```

I suspect this is because when `key.authenticate` is trying to verify the jwt is still valid it calls `performance.now`, which as per [this forum post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-workers-how-do-i-measure-execution-time-of-my-method/69672/3) is not provided by cloudflare workers to prevent timing attacks. I don't fully understand how webassembly works, but I do know that I can polyfill `performance.now` in javascript as is done [here](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5438650).

How could I use this polyfill in a webassembly environment?

Comment: Is the code at `331:15` just a call to `performance.now()`? I haven't used Cloudflare Workers, but I would assume that you could just provide the JS polyfill in the generated file.

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, `331:15` is just a call to `performance.now`. I'm wondering if I can do it in Rust itself though, I would prefer to do it in the source code and not have to do custom post-processing. I am also unsure if the wrangler build process would even allow me to do that.

Comment: Can you provide the command you're using to build `index_bg.mjs`?

Comment: `wrangler dev`, which uses Cloudflare's workers CLI to start a dev server. According to it's log it immediately runs `cargo install -q worker-build && worker-build --release`. I'm pretty sure that `worker-build` is just an alias for `wasm-pack build`, both have the same terminal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all instances of `performace.now()` after the file builds:

```
$ sed -i '' 's/performance.now()/Date.now()/' index_bg.mjs
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`perf_hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) in the NodeJS runtime environment.

```
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks'
```

Otherwise declare a global `performance` object with stub functions:

```
const performance = {
  now: () => Date.now(), // milliseconds used for timing diffs
}
```

Comment: I think that would work, what would I need to write in Rust to generate that global performance object? Or do I need to concatenate text to index_bg.mjs in some sort of post-processing?

Comment: Rust is not calling `performance.now()`. That JavaScript code must be added in the JS runtime environment before the error occurs in `index_bg.mjs`.

Comment: Right, my question is more about how exactly to add the JavaScript to the `index_bg_mjs`. My understanding is that if I directly modify `index_bg.mjs` it will just get overwritten whenever I build the project. The code in that file is generated from my `src/lib.rs`, so I am asking more how to go about writing the proper Rust wasm_bindgen code so that the necessary polyfill gets generated everytime I build.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the js_sys Reflect library to assign `Date.now` to `performance.now` through the global scope.

```
use js_sys::{global, Reflect, Object};

pub fn polyfill() {
    let global = global();
    //let performance = {}
    let performance = Object::new();
    //performance.now = global.Date.now
    Reflect::set(
        &performance,
        &"now".into(),
        &Reflect::get(
            &Reflect::get(&global, &"Date".into()).unwrap(),
            &"now".into()
        ).unwrap()
    ).unwrap();
    //global.performance = performance
    Reflect::set(
        &global,
        &"performance".into(),
        &performance
    ).unwrap();
}
```

Then make sure you call polyfill before you need `performance.now`